# Passing value in an EditText from activity to view class

Tags: android, android-intent, view, android-activity

I have this EditText that contains the value that I wanted to pass to the view class(not an activity). However, i could not. I have tried passing the value back to the MainActivity and tries to access the value from the view class but it failed.

This is from the NameActivity where the EditText contains the name :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(NameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
           String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
           intent.putExtra("name",name);
```

This is from my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         Intent i = getIntent();
         String name = i.getStringExtra("name"); 

         }
}
```

Did i do it the right way? what can i do so that i could access the value in my view class?

Comment: Where is the view class MainActivity is also a Activity class

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to update the Views contents based on the value that is passed in the EditText view? You seem to be making the right steps. Where do you start your intent?

Comment: You could save the data using SharedPreferences and retrieve them in another class or activity.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

You are missing your @Override annotation for the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method in your MainActivity.

Also you should make sure that your nameEditText is a Class Member Variable and not just a member inside your onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) method of your NameActivity.class so you can access it after an action is performed, such as a button click.

Such as:

```
public class NameActivity extends Activity(){

   // Now the EditText is accessible anywhere in this Activity
   TextView nameEditText = null;

   // Dont forget to add the override annotation
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.name_activity_layout);

       // Find the UI ELement by its Id
       nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditTextId);


    }

    // Then whatever Action Triggers your new Intent should include 
    // the code above which creates and starts the new intent however your are doing this
    public void actionPerformedAndNewActivity(){

      // Create a new Intent
      Intent intent = new Intent(NameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      // get the text from the UI EditText
      String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();

      // Add it to the intent Extras
      intent.putExtra("name",name);

      // Missing this Line, start the new Activity
      startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And then in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   // Override onCreate
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Get the Intent that started this Activity
     Intent i = getIntent();

     // Grab the Name from the calling Intent Extras
     String name = i.getStringExtra("name"); 

 }
}
```

Comment: I got it! but how do i access the String name from another class(not an activity)? I have this view class that does drawing of rectangles.

Comment: Okay, this is a little bit more work but also do able. Can you share the View Class that draws the rectangle ?